# Dual kitchen sink is draining very slow

Tags: drain, sink, blockage

my cousin-in law's sink is draining very slow.
I believe it is because she has been washing guinea pig grass/hay or something else down the sink, and now there is a blockage(s) somewhere.
After some googling I decided that its probably best to take the trap off and clean it.
The problem is the sink pipes do not exactly resemble anything from the tutorials I have seen on the internet.
Please note this is a sink in Sweden, so things might be different and not up to code.

[image: Picture of sink pipes]

The red arrow points at a pipe that goes off into a wall (and I assume to her dishwasher as it is the only thing in that direction)
The two green arrows go to each sink basin respectfully.
The purple goes nowhere. It is simply sealed off and hangs a little off frame.
The yellow is something I do not know what is. I have researched and it seems to be a "Bottle Trap"
The black arrow pipe just goes off into the wall. (Must be the drain)

Both sink basins drain very slowly, which is why I assume there is a blockage in the trap.
However it may be possible there is just a blockage in both sink basin drain pipes.
What do you all think the problem is? How would you clean it?
I also do not see any slip-nuts to loosen?

Thank you for your time in advance, and please excuse any grammatical mistakes, as I am Danish.

Comment: I believe your assessment of washing fibrous material down the drain is 100% the cause of the clog! I believe you do have a bottle trap instead of a P-trap or S-trap. Either it's glued together, or, possibly, the whole trap will unscrew just below the lower horizontal drain line. Try using a snake down each sink bowl to clear their drain lines as a starter.

Comment: Is that an open stub-out right below the dishwasher connection?

Answer (score 2):

I have no first-hand experience with non-North-American plumbing systems, however, I think we do occasionally find a bottle trap here. It stands to reason that a trap must be serviceable. Looking carefully at the rim of the gray plastic bowl portion one can see a pattern of light and dark stripes from the reflection of the camera flash. These stripes suggest a threaded joint lies within.

Try using your hands, a strap wrench, pliers, or other tools to unscrew that bowl from the bottom of the assembly. Have a catch basin ready underneath as there will certainly be foul-smelling and unpleasant-appearing material draining out when the trap is opened.

The picture is rotated just slightly from the vertical but it appears to me that the threads are conventional right-hand orientation. Arranged as it is a wrench positioned with the handle extending to the right should be pulled toward the viewer to loosen the trap bowl.

Comment: I think you're right... but I sure don't see any _"light and dark stripes"_ on there!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like You have this:

[image]

That down cup is removable - can be screwed off  (marked yellow on Your pic)

Remember to put some bowl or bucket under to prewent spil of very nasty stuff.

Good to be to replace seal.

Comment: Yes exactly! I found the model, a "prevex flexloc 2". The trap at the bottom can be unscrewed. 

It was dirty, but not fully blocked as I imagined. I did some troubleshooting and came to the conclusion that the left pipe was blocked with something. I ended up taking the entire pipe system off, and pushing a metal wire up and down it. The metal wire and cleaning trap has fixed the problem. 

Thank you everyone!